# Finding a right" (fast and accurate) way for finding with what to check the collision for 2d games. c++

Tags: c++, maps, collision-detection, tiles, 2d-games

I am creating 2d rpg game. For maps I use 32x32 tiles. Objects like player and monsters have different sprite-mask width and height and they move not in tiles, but by x and y.
So I am trying to find a "right" (fast and accurate) way for finding with what to check the collision, between player and tiles, player and monsters, monsters and tiles, monster and players.

For Collision detection I use: rectangle to rectangle, circle to circle(distance), rectangle to circle, and circle to rectangle collision check.

So for example I have a map: 1600x1600 width and height. Divide it by 32 and I have 50x50 tile map.

I made an 2d array of bool:

```
bool tile_area[50][50];
```

So for every non-collision-free tile, it will hold 1, and for collision-free tile it will hold 0.So for example, if the player is on tile_area[1][1] and wants to move right it checks the collision in tile_area[2][1], if tile is collision-free then it moves. Same goes for monster, everything is perfect here.

But this type of collision detection is different between moving objects like player and monsters, monster and monster.
If in 1 map I have like 200-300 moving objects, its not very good idea to check the collision of main moving object with the rest of all the other objects every pixel it moves.

So I thought of an idea, of dividing the map of areas for the objects also, so now I got a 2d array of struct of obj_area[x][y]. This struct holds a vector of object structs "vector obj_list;", because not just 1 object can be in that area.

```
struct obj_area{
vector<obj> obj_list;
};

obj_area o_Area[50][50];
```

I believe I could just make an 2d array of vector of structs :D Don't know for sure ;D

So when the player or monster moves, for example to x 210 and y 300 so it will be added to obj_area[210/32=7][300/32=9] and if it would want to move right, it would check first the tile_area[8][9] and if free, then with all the objects in the vector obj_area[8][9]. So if it is free also, it reallocates to obj_area[8][9] from obj_area[7][9] <- in this point I don't know if it is a good idea for reallocation, I would need to delete it from the old vector and add it to a new one, and that would be needed in every step of movement.

I have another idea, but I don't know if it would be better or possible, 
If I had a map of structs, and pair of x,y as its key value, so theoretically every time object moves, and needs to reallocate, I would just need to change the key value of that maps pair.

I would be very grateful for any of your thoughts and maybe better ideas :)

Comment: Isn't this just a generic collision detection problem? The pixel-based design is irrelevant, unless you are constrained in memory or something. Just use any kind of acceleration data structure for collision detection, like quad trees or spatial hashing.

Comment: Would that be near to O(1) operations? because I am searching something similar to it.

Comment: Yes, spatial hashing is close to O(1), with some tuning. Unless you have thousands of entities, even O(log n) will be fast enough.

Comment: well how I understand spatial hashing, it divides the map into a grid of small rectangles, like areas in my idea.

Answer (score 2):

First a few remarks regarding your ideas:

- do not put your objects (are these the structs you are talking about?) into your lookup structure; using pointers is going to save you a lot of time copying data
- only use `vector`s if you know the number of elements in a single one is going to be small; removing an item requires iterating over the whole vector (has linear time complexity)

And now a suggestion:

If most of your objects are small, you could attach to each its current bounding box. Then if you keep two maps (one for x- and one for y-axis), mapping coordinates of the corners of the bounding boxes to their respective objects, you can:

- update the maps in logarithmic time (small even for thousands of objects) whenever an object moves
- check only for collisions with object that intersect with the one you are currently dealing with on one of the axis (pick the one on which the range has fewer elements, `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` are your friends here)

Comment: yes those objects are structs, that hold x,y, sprite/mask width height, and other stuff. All object size are different. Ok if I wont put those structs in lookup vector, so should I put pointers there? vector of pointers? is that what you mean?

Comment: @DainiusKreivys: Yes, I mean vector of pointers. If you are going to be moving this data between your vectors (or whatever) and your structs are more than a couple of bytes in size, storing pointers will make the modifications faster. On the other hand, the pointers force an extra indirection, which might make the cpu's prefether's work harder and slow down the accesses...

Comment: then what about boost::shared_ptr? maybe those will come in handy ?

Comment: @DainiusKreivys: If your lookup structures are the only place where you store your objects (i.e., the objects are owned by the lookup sturctures), then use a `shared_ptr` or a `unique_ptr` (the latter has less overhead, but it only works if your objects are pointed to from one place at a time). If you store your game objects somewhere else (which seems more natural to me) and use the lookup structures only for... lookup, then just go use plain pointers -- this will make it clear that there is no ownership associated with them.